# Prevent code replication with lambda functions when using out parameters

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, lambda, out

I have to parse the content of many TextBox that contain various numeric data types (`int`, `double`, ...).
To be valid, the text does not only have to be parsable as `int`, or `dobule` or whatever, it also has to be in a certain range.

I have this function:

```
    private static bool validateDoubleInRange(TextBox txtBox,
        double rangeMin, double rangeMax,
        string errorMessage, ErrorProvider ep, out double? result)
    {
        double tmpResult;
        if (double.TryParse(txtBox.Text, out tmpResult))
        {
            // Ok it's a double but is it valid?
            if (tmpResult > rangeMin && tmpResult < rangeMax)
            {
                // Yes it is
                result = tmpResult;
                ep.SetError(txtBox, string.Empty);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                // No
                result = null;
                ep.SetError(txtBox, errorMessage);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Not even a double
            result = null;
            ep.SetError(txtBox, errorMessage);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This works for fields that i know should contain a `double`. To parse a field that should contain an `int` i would need to write a function that is almost identical except for the `double.TryParse(string, out double)` that would become `int.TryParse(string, out int)` and the signature of the function that would change from `out double?` to `out int?`

I've created a delegate to be used instead of the type specific `type.TryParse(...)`:

```
private delegate bool GenericTryParse(TextBox txtBox, out ??? result);
```

the previous function would contain en extra parameter that will be of type `GenericTryParse`

And the call (`int` version) would become:

```
validateGenericNumberInRange(txtBox, 0, 100, errorMessage, ep,
 (TextBox tb, out int r) => { return int.TryParse(tb.Text, out r)?true:false; },
 out result);
```

The problem is, i'm still bound to the `out` parameter type, i can't (or don't know how to) declare `GenericTryParse` without specifying the `out` result type.

Is there a way around this problem, how would you do that?

Comment: There is never any reason to write `?true:false`

Comment: @SLaks what do you meen? Is it a bad practice or just wrong or what? (i'm kind of new to c#)

Comment: It's useless.  You already have a boolean.

Comment: @SLaks oh... yea... i feel dumb now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx):

```
private delegate bool GenericTryParse<T>(TextBox txtBox, out T result);
```